# How to represent this array re-ordering example using Immutable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutable.js

From this code sample for react-dnd:

https://github.com/gaearon/react-dnd/blob/master/examples/04%20Sortable/Simple/Container.js#L46-L53

```
this.setState(update(this.state, {
  cards: {
    $splice: [
      [dragIndex, 1],
      [hoverIndex, 0, dragCard]
    ]
  }
}));
```

I'm trying to carry out this same action using Immutable, but can't figure out how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

```
const cards = state.get('cards');
const newState = state.set('cards',
  cards.splice(dragIndex, 1)
  .splice(hoverIndex, 0, dragCard));
```